# how to stop displaying textarea if the previous text area is empty?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` that is displaying `textarea`s onclick.

I want it to:

- display the first `textarea`
- check if first `textarea` is empty
- if it is empty do not display the second `textarea`
- if it is not empty display the second `textarea`

Html codde:

```
    <div class= "flex-container">    
        <div id= "cardarea" class ="parent2">
            <span><b id ="cardtitle">Stuff To Try (this is a list)</b>
   </span>
            <span>
          <i class ="fa fa-ellipsis-h" title ="List Actions" tabindex="0" 
     data-trigger ="focus" data-toggle="popover" ></i>
            </span>
            <div id="popover-content" style="display:none;">
                    <ul style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" 
      class ="pop-over-list" >
                        <li >
                            <a id = "newcard" href="#" onclick="addcard()" >
                            <b style ="color: #444444">Add Card...</b>
                            </a>

                       </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
   function addcard() {

  var counter = 0;

  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
  var button = $(document.createElement('button'));

  newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-top", "6px");
  newTextBoxDiv.css("width", "210px");
  newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-left", "8px");
  newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-bottom", "6px");
  newTextBoxDiv.css("border-radius", "5px");
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter('#cardtitle');
  button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(newTextBoxDiv);
  button.css("margin-left", "8px");
  button.css("height", "30px");
  button.css("width", "55px");
  button.css("margin-bottom", "6px");
  button.addClass("btn btn-success");
  button.text("Add");
  button.css("font-weight", "bold");
  //button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(" <span class='glyphicon 
  glyphicon - remove '</span>");

  if ($(newTextBoxDiv).val().length != 0) {
    alert("hello1");
  } else if ($(newTextBoxDiv).val().length === 0) {
    $('#newcard').hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing its value to an empty string?

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: What **exactly** is your question?

Comment: i have added the html code @Negi Rox

Comment: so basically what I understand, you want a one text area with the title on click of add card, and then you want a functionality on addcard button if the text area is not empty then only you can able to create a new text area? correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. The first one should appear as the `addcard` is clicked. And the next one will appear when the previous has some text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty messy. You are using jQuery but not in the jQuery way. It looks like you are mixing vanilla JavaScript and jQuery. Also, you are appending a lot of CSS using jQuery, if you want to style it, style it using CSS. As far as the issue goes, you want to append a new `textarea` element only if the previous one has few characters in that.

So I've wrote some code from scratch as yours was very messy. Here, before I add a new `textarea`, I select the last appended `textarea` using `wrapper.find('textarea').last().val().length`, if it returns more than `0`, it will append a new `textarea` else it will just ignore.

```js
var wrapper = $('#show-textarea');
$('#add-textarea').on('click', function() {
  if(wrapper.find('textarea').last().val().length) {
    wrapper.append('<textarea></textarea>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-textarea">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<input type="button" id="add-textarea" value="Add Textarea">
```

> Note: Am not using `.trim()` here, but I would recommend using it. If
>   you don't, user can create a new `textarea` by adding a blank space in
>   the previous `textarea` element and it will happily return the
>   `length` of `1`.

Comment: Thank u.. Yes the code is a bit messy.  This worked. But u have the first`text area` already set. I need the first text area to appear on the button click as well.

Comment: @sanjana all you need is a minor tweak.. try it out, if you can't, reply to this comment and I'll help you out

Comment: yes. what i tried was just hiding and showing the element. This worked for me!   : )

Comment: Or you tweak the if condition and add a text area if you don't find a textarea under wrapper element

Answer (score 0):

Pass the "counter" from where "addcard" is being called. Maintain it's value on the global level.

```
function addcard(counter) {

    var oldTextBoxDiv = $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter);
    if (oldTextBoxDiv.val().length != 0) {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        var button = $(document.createElement('button'));

        newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-top", "6px");
        newTextBoxDiv.css("width", "210px");
        newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-left", "8px");
        newTextBoxDiv.css("margin-bottom", "6px");
        newTextBoxDiv.css("border-radius", "5px");
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter('#cardtitle');
        button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(newTextBoxDiv);
        button.css("margin-left", "8px");
        button.css("height", "30px");
        button.css("width", "55px");
        button.css("margin-bottom", "6px");
        button.addClass("btn btn-success");
        button.text("Add");
        button.css("font-weight", "bold");
        button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(" <span class='glyphicon glyphicon - remove '</span>");

       // Increase the value of counter
       counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please enter the data into the previous text area");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global variable so you can check length of previous textarea
var counter =0;
function addcard() {  
if(counter>0){
// Checkfor previous textarea
var oldValue=$('#TextBoxDiv'+counter).val();
//Check for null or empty
if(!oldValue){
return;
}
}
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea')) .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter); var button = $(document.createElement('button')); newTextBoxDiv.css( "margin-top","6px"); newTextBoxDiv.css("width","210px"); newTextBoxDiv.css( "margin-left","8px"); newTextBoxDiv.css( "margin-bottom","6px"); newTextBoxDiv.css( "border-radius","5px"); newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter('#cardtitle'); button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(newTextBoxDiv); button.css("margin-left","8px"); button.css("height","30px"); button.css("width","55px"); button.css( "margin-bottom","6px"); button.addClass("btn btn-s`enter code here`uccess"); button.text("Add"); button.css("font-weight","bold"); //button.appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter(" <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove '</span>"); 
counter++;
 }
```

Here when addcard funtion is call its first check for function is call for first time then no need to check for previous textarea and add new textarea otherwise it will check for previous textarea is empty or null if its is then exit from function otherwise add neww